# Composites from -σις words

Tags: greek, morphology, derivation

How does one form composites from words in '-σις'?
For example, if one wishes to name the fear of vaxing fat,
using πάχυνσις, is it παχυνσοφοβία; or παχυνσεοφοβία?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My expectation would be that the base stem would be used, thus παχυνσιφοβία.  I haven't found a lot of examples to support this, but there is, for example, πραξι‐κοπεῖν "to take by surprise" from πρᾶξις and στασι‐ωρός "watcher of the station" from στάσις.

P.S. What's "vaxing fat"?